# R stack data frame by rows

Tags: r, stack

I am trying to do stack. My data is

```
set.seed(1)
x<-runif(5)
y<-runif(5)
dat<-cbind(x,y)
dat<-as.data.frame(dat)
dat
   x          y
1 0.2655087 0.89838968
2 0.3721239 0.94467527
3 0.5728534 0.66079779
4 0.9082078 0.62911404
5 0.2016819 0.06178627


stack(dat)

   values ind
1  0.26550866   x
2  0.37212390   x
3  0.57285336   x
4  0.90820779   x
5  0.20168193   x
6  0.89838968   y
7  0.94467527   y
8  0.66079779   y
9  0.62911404   y
10 0.06178627   y
```

However, this stacks by column i.e. it takes `y` column and puts it 
below `x`. What I want to do is to stack it by row like this:

```
0.2655087    x
0.89838968   y
0.3721239    x
0.94467527   y
0.5728534    x
0.66079779   y
0.9082078    x
0.62911404   y
0.2016819    x
0.06178627   y
```

How can this be done using `stack`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A base R method that exploits the column dominant storage of matrices. The columns x and y are turned into a matrix, which is transposed and then unwrapped into a vector. Since we know the structure (ordering) of the resulting vector, we build the x y names into a new variable:

```
data.frame(values=c(t(data.matrix(dat))), ind=I(rep(colnames(dat), nrow(dat))))
```

Which returns

```
       values ind
1  0.26550866   x
2  0.89838968   y
3  0.37212390   x
4  0.94467527   y
5  0.57285336   x
6  0.66079779   y
7  0.90820779   x
8  0.62911404   y
9  0.20168193   x
10 0.06178627   y
```

I wrapped the x y vector in `I` to "insulate" it, so that it would return as a character vector within the `data.frame` function rather than as a factor, which is the default. Using the stringsAsFactors=TRUE argument in `data.frame` would also return the x y vector as a character type.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have to use stack()? This will do the trick:

```
# Creating your data frame
set.seed(1)
x<-runif(5)
y<-runif(5)
dat<-cbind(x,y)
dat<-as.data.frame(dat)
dat

# Stacking the data
dat2 <- rbind(data.frame("Value"=dat$x,"Ind"="x","Row"=seq(nrow(dat))),
      data.frame("Value"=dat$y,"Ind"="y","Row"=seq(nrow(dat))))

# Ordering the data
dat2 <- dat2[order(dat2$Row),setdiff(names(dat2),"Row")]

        Value Ind
1  0.26550866   x
6  0.89838968   y
2  0.37212390   x
7  0.94467527   y
3  0.57285336   x
8  0.66079779   y
4  0.90820779   x
9  0.62911404   y
5  0.20168193   x
10 0.06178627   y
```

Answer (score 0):

We could simply do:

```
data.frame(values=matrix(t(dat)), ind=colnames(dat))

       # values ind
# 1  0.26550866   x
# 2  0.89838968   y
# 3  0.37212390   x
# 4  0.94467527   y
# 5  0.57285336   x
# 6  0.66079779   y
# 7  0.90820779   x
# 8  0.62911404   y
# 9  0.20168193   x
# 10 0.06178627   y
```